# XSLT - how can I sort something to the bottom of the file

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Is there a way to detect elements with a certain child element and then move all such elements to the bottom of the file?

Example:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <d />
    </b>
    <b>
        <c />
    </b>
    <b>
        <d />
    </b>
</a>
```

In this case, I'd want all of the `b`s that contain `c` to be at the bottom of the file:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <d />
    </b>
    <b>
        <d />
    </b>
    <b>
        <c />
    </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a template for `a`

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::b[c])]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="b[c]"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy other nodes unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use sort, you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="b">
            <xsl:sort select="not(c)" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```